# How would I align my input field and button upward to make it inline with other buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, debugging, bootstrap-4

I would like to move my button directly upward in a responsive way so that it's inline with the iOS and Android buttons using `Bootstrap`.

My attempt in the code below gives me the output which's the screenshot provided but isn't what I want

I've tried a lot of things throughout SO and the web but nothing seems to be working.  I would add some CSS from the outside but I feel like it wouldn't be as responsive as it should.  I must be overlooking something miniscule.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
import React from 'react';

const footer = () => {
    return(
        <footer className="container">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 center">
                <img className="iosBtn imgCenter img-responsive" src="https://website.com/images/website/Home/iphone.png?v=6.97"/>
                <img className="img-responsive" src="https://website.com/images/website/Home/google_play.png?v=6.97"/>
            </div>

            {/* I want to move this upward */}
            <form className="form-inline float-right">
                <div className="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                    <input className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <hr/>

            <div className="row text-center">
            <div className="col-sm">
            <a href="#">WINNERS</a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm">
            <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm">
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm">
            <a href="#">SWEEPSTAKES</a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm">
            <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm">
            <a href="#">TERMS</a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <br/>

            <div className="text-center">
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-link fa fa-facebook"></a>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-link fa fa-instagram"></a>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-link fa fa-youtube"></a>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-link fa fa-twitter"></a>
            <p className="text-center">website</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    );
};

export default footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your html, the form has the `float: right;` style applied which is causing the weird behavior.

I'd recommend using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead:

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
  </div>
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `div` with the images and your `form` in one `div`. And play with `display: inline-block` and `float: left` on the two. If nothing works, try to wrap the `form` also with another `div` and have the `inline-block` there.

See [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/apappas1129/np1g7je2/3/)